# SqlDependency not working with Entity Framework

Tags: caching, entity-framework-4.1, sqldependency

I have an issue when trying to start the SqlDependency.

The error informs me: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

The connectionstring is the following when retrieved from the immediate window right before it crashes.

```
?objectContext.Connection.ConnectionString
 "metadata=res://*/YeagerTech.csdl|res://*/YeagerTech.ssdl|res://*/YeagerTech.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=Bill-PC;initial catalog=YeagerTech;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework\""
```

Here is the code. It crashes on the Start method. Apparently, it doesn't think the EF connectionstring is valid. Any idea of how I can correctly use this?

```
YeagerTechEntities dbContext = new YeagerTechEntities();

            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

            SqlDependency.Start(objectContext.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because EF connection string is not valid for `SqlDependency`. It works only with `EntityConnection` but `SqlDependency` uses `SqlConnection`. So you must either use direct connection string in your dbContext or extract database connection string from entity connection.

Either:

```
var connectionString = dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

Or

```
var connectionString = ((EnityConnection)objectContext.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
```

Anyway EF doesn't play very well with `SqlDependency`. SqlDependency expects that you write SQL queries yourselves and have them under your control.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the code snippet that I got it to work is the following:

```
YeagerTechEntities dbContext = new YeagerTechEntities();

ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

Application["dbContext"] = dbContext;

objectContext.Connection.ConnectionString =    
   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YeagerTechEntities"].ConnectionString;

SqlDependency.Start(((System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection)
   .StoreConnection.ConnectionString);
```

YeagerTechEntities is the EF connectionstring.